# Requiring subclasses to implment method without being public

Tags: javascript, typescript

I have the following interface:

```
import * as Bluebird from "bluebird";
import { Article } from '../../Domain/Article/Article';

export interface ITextParsingService {
    parsedArticle : Article;
    getText(uri : string) : Bluebird<any>;
}
```

and the following class that implements such an interface:

```
import * as Bluebird from 'bluebird';
import * as requestPromise from 'request-promise';
import ApplicationConfiguration from '../../../../config/ApplicationConfiguration';
import { ITextParsingService } from '../ITextParsingService';
import { Article } from '../../../Domain/Article/Article';

export class DiffbotTextParsingService implements ITextParsingService {
    public parsedArticle: Article;
    private articleApiEndpoint;

    constructor() {
        this.articleApiEndpoint = "https://api.diffbot.com/v3/article";
    }

    public getText(url: string) : Bluebird<any> {
        return requestPromise(this.articleApiEndpoint, {
            qs : {
                "url" : url,
                "token" : ApplicationConfiguration.Diffbot.developerToken
            },
            headers : {
                'User-Agent' : 'Request-Promise'
            },
            json : true
        }).then((diffbotResponse) => {
            this.mapReponseToArticle(diffbotResponse.objects[0]);
        }).catch((errorMessage) => {
            return errorMessage;
        })
    }

    private mapReponseToArticle(response : any) {
        this.parsedArticle = new Article(response.diffbotUri,
                                         response.title,
                                         response.author,
                                         new URL(response.authorUrl),
                                         response.text,
                                         new URL(response.pageUrl),
                                         new Date(response.date),
                                         response.humanLanguage);
    }
}
```

How can I make it a requirement that all classes that implement `ITextParsingService` also implement `mapResponseToArticle`, which basically takes the service's response and maps it to a common domain object? I don't see any reason why it should be a public method, but I also can't see how I can enforce such a requirement from implementing classes. Any suggestions for an alternative pattern?

Comment: The inability for an interface to enforce private methods is common in many languages.  Why would you want to force another developer to implement a method you will never be able to call.  What if one day you decide this shouldn't be a separate method,  but instead should be inside another method.

Comment: Ah yes, I understand. But then is there some alternative to ensure that the required `parsedArticle` object is properly constructed based on the service's response by the developer? Or is this something that I should not be concerned about and is implied if someone were to create a new service that implements this interface?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> ITextParsingService also implement mapResponseToArticle, which basically takes the service's response and maps it to a common domain object? I don't see any reason why it should be a public method, but I also can't see how I can enforce such a requirement from implementing classes.

There is no way to achieve that.

> Any suggestions for an alternative pattern?

Use the common naming convention and call it `_mapResponseToArticle`. `_` prefix is conventional JS for internal stuff and is defacto in raw JS where `private` isn't available  (today ... its coming soon)